# Change colour of placeholder text underline

Tags: html, css, input, placeholder

[image]

Basically I'm doing a contact form, the text input design as shown above.
And the "First Name*" is a placeholder text.

Does anyone know how to change the placeholder text underline to different colour to the placeholder text.

```css
input {
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: rgba(251,175,93,1); 
 font-weight: normal;
 text-decoration: underline;  
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
 color: rgba(251,175,93,1); 
 font-weight: normal;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {   /* Older versions of Firefox */
 color: rgba(251,175,93,1);    
 font-weight: normal;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { 
 color: rgba(251,175,93,1); 
 font-weight: normal;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.textinput{ 
  color: #585857; 
  outline: none; 
  width: 230px; 
  margin: 0 0 15px 0; 
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2; 
  font-size: 13px; 
  display: block;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="textinput" placeholder=" First Name*">
```

Comment: There's currently no simple solution to this, however hopefully "text-decoration styling" will become more commonly accepted and make this easy: http://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Firefox & Safari solution

You can use [text-decoration-color](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-decoration-color.asp) css property like this :

```
input::-moz-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: rgba(251,175,93,1);  
}
```

**Result :** [image]
See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kycykgyx/) for more information

**Note that it will only work on :**

- Firefox 6+ (with `-moz-`) - *Tested*
- Safari 9+ (with `-webkit-`)

[See for yourself](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration-color)

---

### Chrome & Opera solution

You can use both `input-placeholder` pseudo-element and `border-bottom` css property like this :

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(251,175,93,1);
}
```

**Result :**
[image]
See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0veooq2/) for more information

**Note that it will only work on :**

- Chrome 48+ (with `-webkit-`) - *Tested*
- Opera 36+
- Safari 9+

[See for yourself](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder-shown)

---

Comment: Thanks. This is what I want but so sad, it doesn't works on chrome :(

Comment: @Eelyn Yep what a pity .. This shouldn't be hard to implement, I hope they'll do it soon

Comment: Yes! Surprisingly it doesn't works on chrome. Or do you have other solution? As in not using text underline.

Comment: @Eelyn have you got the latest version of chrome?

Comment: Not yet. I'm using version 50.0.2661.102. Why?

Comment: @James111 Nah it won't change anything. I'm on the latest version and I can't see anything

Comment: @Eelyn Updated my post with the Chrome solution :)

Comment: Wow, cool. But the border-bottom length is same as the text input width.

Comment: @Eelyn Yeah I know but I couldn't get better than this. But btw, the image you put in your question displays the same effect

Comment: @tektiv I just realized it's about the same. My fault, haha! Because firefox is different. Thank you so much, I have clicked to accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one it works

```
 input {
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: rgba(9,0,255,1); 
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: underline;  
  text-decoration-color:rgba(255,60,0,1);
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: rgba(9,0,255,1);  
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color:rgba(255,60,0,1);
}
input:-moz-placeholder {   /* Older versions of Firefox */
    color: rgba(9,0,255,1);  
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color:rgba(255,60,0,1);
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { 
    color: rgba(9,0,255,1); 
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color:rgba(255,60,0,1);
}

.textinput{ 
  color: black; 
  outline: none; 


  width: 230px; 
  margin: 0 0 15px 0; 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  font-size: 13px; 
  display: block;  
}
```